# ping successfully but gethostbyname() returns null

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I'm programming for a device running Linux OS.

The device runs `ping` command to `youtube.com` successfully. However, in source code, if I call `gethostbyname("youtube.com")`, the function returns `NULL`.

---

**UPDATE LOG**

My code looks like this (this is just a short pseudo code to describe my issue, not full code)

```c
void my_func()
{
    struct hostent     *hostEntry;
    
    hostEntry = gethostbyname("youtube.com");
    if (hostEntry) {
        // gethostbyname() resolve host name successfully, no need to care
    } else {
        printf("Fail to get host, herrno=%d, strErr=%s\n", h_errno, hstrerror(h_errno));
    }
}
```

And the device's output when `gethostbyname()` returns `NULL` is

```sh
Fail to get host, herrno=1, strErr=Unknown host
```

This is the device's output when I exit the program and run `ping youtube.com`

```sh
$ ping youtube.com
PING youtube.com (64.233.189.91): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 64.233.189.91: seq=0 ttl=55 time=57.824 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.189.91: seq=1 ttl=55 time=56.306 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.189.91: seq=2 ttl=55 time=56.790 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.189.91: seq=3 ttl=55 time=56.831 ms
64 bytes from 64.233.189.91: seq=4 ttl=55 time=56.417 ms
```

What should I check now?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I've just updated my question

Comment: @xuanduc611 thanks, comment deleted, close vote retracted and upvoted :D and you run ping on the same device? Does the problem indeed manifest if you just have `int main(void) { my_func(); }` + #includes?

Comment: - the device executes `my_func()` is the device that runs `ping`.
- "Does the problem indeed manifest..." => I'm not sure, the src code for this device is extremely huge

Comment: You can look at what ping is using to resolve names. Either use a big hammer like `ltrace` or look at the source code of your ping. If your ping is from busybox, then the answer would be [getaddrinfo](https://elixir.bootlin.com/busybox/1.27.2/source/libbb/xconnect.c#L285)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add [`res_init()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/res_init) to resolve this issue and fortunately, it works.

```
#include <resolv.h>

void my_func()
{
    struct hostent     *hostEntry;
    
    hostEntry = gethostbyname("youtube.com");
    if (hostEntry) {
        res_init();
        hostEntry = gethostbyname("youtube.com");
    }

    if (hostEntry) {
        // gethostbyname() resolve host name successfully, no need to care
    } else {
        printf("Fail to get host, herrno=%d, strErr=%s\n", h_errno, hstrerror(h_errno));
    }
}
```

This may be the reason why the function helps

> The res_init() function reads the configuration files (see resolv.conf(5)) to get the default domain name, search order and name server address(es).